# Alarm system design

Tags: database-design, alarm

I've been asked to design an alarm system that would allow some users to create alarms, and others to listen to those alarms and do whatever they need to do.
The users that launch the alarms want to have a **shortcut** (their systems are running Windows XP), so automatically the guys who are listening to possible alarms get the correspondent signal.

That is to say, if a user presses the key combination the petition is made automatically to the security people.

I've thought of developing this by creating a database that would contain location information of all the users in the system, and would also have alarms history.  I was thinking on creating a new row for each alarm a user launches, and then having the security guys looking for new alarms generated. So basically something like:

- On shortcut launch script that creates a new row in ALARMS table.
- Cron or scheduled task on security guys checking for new alarms constantly.

I am pretty new on designing this kind of systems, and I was thinking if this is a good way to go.  Also, I would appreciate if somebody knows how to assign the launch of a script to a system shortcut under Windows.

Appreciate any help, and let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: @Raj More: Did I do something wrong?

Comment: someone voted to close, and I was wondering why.

Comment: @Raj More: Oh ok. I'm pretty new to SO, and I know this kind of "theorical" questions can seem vague somehow, but I believe it's a design question...And no code has been written so far.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly suggest using a message queue for this.  You can submit a new message to the queue with a simple console app (with a shortcut on the desktop or something).

The "listening" systems would be notified immediately and you perform the corresponding action at that time.

Microsoft's built in queues work great:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.aspx

Or you can use RabbitMQ, which is more robust, but harder to get working out of the box.

This will save all the hassle of constantly hitting a database for updates.

Edit:

And, of course, you would also want to record all the calls in a database, for record-keeping.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm pretty new to develop Windows applications, so I would prefer some other solution.  Even though, this seems pretty clean and I'm going to look at it.  How would the listening systems work? It should be a process running all time, and when an alarm exists, pop up a window, but is that possible with messaging?  Thanks.

Comment: You could use a database that is simply queried every minute or something.  The benefit to a message queue is that it notifies the recipient very quickly.  Most other methods have a delay.  You could use direct sockets, but that would be much more difficult.  You can send messages through a queue with very little code, so even though it looks daunting, you'd be surprised at how quickly you'll pick it up.  Search google for "c# message queue tutorial" and you'll find a wealth of information to get started.

Comment: The listening computers "subscribe" to the queue, and as soon as a message arrives, they are notified so they can process it.  Depending on how you set it up, you can have just one computer pick it up, all of them, etc.  RabbitMQ is much more customizable this way than the Microsoft queue, but it could be done with either.

Comment: This is really good information.  I come from a web development side (PHP,MYSQL) , and I believe that is why this "Microsoft Message Queue" scares me.  I'm going to try learning, and will come back if more doubts come.  Appreciate :)

Comment: In that case, RabbitMQ may be more suited to your needs.  It's more friendly with other languages.  It's free, so check it out if Microsoft doesn't seem to integrate the way you want.